# Pattern does not work about lazy regular expressions in json context

Tags: json, regex

I have this context:

```
{"id":"123","title":"aaa","url":"aaaa","visit":"1"},{"id":"456","title":"aaa","url":"aaaa","visit":"0"},{"id":"789","title":"aaa","url":"aaaa","visit":"0"},
```

I want to get all `id` with `visit` equal to `0`.

I write this pattern:

```
{"id":"(.*?)".*?"visit":"0"}
```

As you can see result in here:
https://regex101.com/r/H0LXQ9/2

return `123` and `789` !

But correct return that I expect must be `456` and `789`.

What's correct pattern for it?

Comment: Do you have any idea whether your context is called JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `.*?`, although lazy, will extend until the *first* `"visit":"0"` match succeeds (as opposed to greedy `.*`, which would extend until the *last* match.)

You need to change "any char" pattern to "not a string boundary" and "not an object boundary":

```
{"id":"([^"]*?)"[^}]*?"visit":"0"}
        ^^^^    ^^^^
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/H0LXQ9/3

Please note this would work only until string values contain (escaped) quotes or braces. Generally, **parsing JSON with regex is bad idea**. Use JSON parser and process the resulting objects instead.

Comment: Thanks, the `{"id":"([^}]*?)"[^}]*?"visit":"0"}` pattern also works.

Answer (score 1):

You could use look ahead:

`\d+(?=","title[^}]*?visit":"0"})`

---

https://regex101.com/r/H0LXQ9/4